# Как изменить яркость иконки JButton

Tags: java, swing

Я решил использовать элемент JButton с иконкой в качестве кнопки .Однако столкнулся с тем,что иконка перестала изменять свою яркость при наведении, нажатии, уведении курсора в сторону. Для решения проблемы создал  класс(наследник JButton), который задаёт определённые параметры кнопке и добавляет к ней ChangeListener ,отвечающий за нужные мне действия с внешним видом .
К сожалению, вышло так, что при наведении яркость изменяется ,а по обратному действию - нет! Причём , если  повторять процесс,то кнопка продолжит становиться всё ярче и ярче. Пожалуйста, помогите.
Код:

```
public class JIconButton extends JButton {

BufferedImage img;
ImageIcon DefaultIcon;
public JIconButton (String imgpatch) {//путь к изображению
  setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
  setContentAreaFilled(false);
try {
    img = (BufferedImage)ImageIO.read(new File(imgpatch));
} catch (IOException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
}
DefaultIcon = new ImageIcon(img);
    setIcon(DefaultIcon);
    addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent evt) {
            if (getModel().isPressed()) {

            } else if (getModel().isRollover()==true) {
                float brightenFactor = 1.1f;
                RescaleOp op = new RescaleOp(brightenFactor, 0, null);                  
                setIcon(new ImageIcon(op.filter(img, img)));

            } else if (getModel().isRollover()==false) {
                setIcon(DefaultIcon);
            }
        }

    });
}}
```

Comment: Ещё пытался установить цвет (не используя setIcon(DefaultIcon)) с помощью возведения числа 1.1f в -1 степень , но цвет становился тусклее изначального (возможно float типа недостаточно для хранения точных значений, а RescaleOp не поддерживает double)

Comment: попробуйте вторым параметром в `op.filter` `null` передавать, сейчас вы постоянно обновляете один и тот же `BufferedImage`.

Comment: Это приводит к исчезновению иконки, т.е. кнопка невидима .

Comment: Передача другого Buffered вместо null вообще ни к чему не приводит